# Why the object is returned empty? Android. Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Why the object is returned empty? Android. Retrofit2.

I have a class User:

```
public class User{

    @SerializedName("LOGIN")
    String login;
    @SerializedName("PASSWORD")
    String password;
    @SerializedName("NAME")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("SURNAME")
    String surname;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

This's my JSON:

```
[{
"LOGIN":"TEST",
"PASSWORD":"TEST",
"NAME":"TEST",
"SURNAME":"TEST"
}
]
```

Interface:

```
public interface Link {

@GET("93sZY0Xg")
Call<List<User>> listRepos();

}
```

and class LoginActivity where i use retrofit2:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<List<User>>{

    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://pastebin.com/raw/")
            .build();
    private Link service = retrofit.create(Link.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Call<List<User>> us = service.listRepos();
        us.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

        System.out.println(response.body());
        System.out.println(response.code());

        User us = response.body().get(0);

        System.out.println(us.getName());

        for(User m: response.body()){

            System.out.println( m.getName());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

        System.out.println(t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I get this response: response.code() is 200;

I/System.out: [com.example.com.dataBase.User@b789a]

I tried getName from class User, but all variables is null.

Why are the values empty? Where's my mistakes?

Comment: problem with json response, it is a json array not a json object and you are trying to put object in model class, try to change json response otherwise get json object from jsonarray then put it into model class

Comment: Please provide the retrofit version

Comment: @Expose
@SerializedName("LOGIN")
    String login;

Try this

Comment: @VinayakB retrofit:2.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following, expose annotation is important to set value in fields

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("movie_id")
private String movieId;

@Expose
@SerializedName("movie_name")
private String movieName;

@Expose
@SerializedName("movie_poster")
private String moviePoster;

@Expose
@SerializedName("movie_dialog_count")
private String movieDialogCount;
```

Comment: Welcome @KirillZorin